# How can Apache IoTDB return the amount of time series under certain root?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Does anyone know how to calculate the number of time series under certain root of Apache IoTDB? I tried to use "count" command, but the result did not come out, maybe because the amount that needs to come back is too large. How to know the amount the data then?

Does anyone can deal this problem？ Help please